# How to call a CSV resource

Tags: 8

I have a decoupled Drupal website and I want to call a REST resource outputing CSV, using the CSV Serialization module. I have also configured REST UI to accept CSV in that particular resource.

I tried sending headers with `Content-Type: application/csv`, or `Content-Type: text/csv`, I'm sending `_format=csv` as a GET parameter, but the only response I'm getting is:

```
   "No route found that matches ""Content-Type: application/csv"""
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've found out I also have to send the Accept header:

```
Accept: text/csv
```

I'm also sending some parameters on POST and PUT, in JSON format (the resource also accepts JSON for input), so I also send:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

and, on the query string, as mentioned, _format=csv